# C API Library for Solving Sparse Systems of Linear Equations?

Tags: c, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, equations

I need to solve a large, sparse system of linear equations from a program written in D.  Ideally I'd like a library with a D-style interface, but I doubt one exists.  However, D can directly access C APIs.  Therefore, please suggest some libraries that solve large, sparse systems of linear equations with the following characteristics:

1. Exposes a C API.
2. Free/open source.  Preferably non-copyleft, too, but this is not a hard requirement.
3. Well-tested and debugged.  Easy to set up and use.  Not written by academics just to get a paper on their method and then completely unmaintained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classical library for sparse problem is [suite-sparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/). You have packages on many systems. Matlab uses it internally.

Comment: I cannot comment on your post yet (not enough rep...). But I particularly appreciate your impression on what academics produce. BTW suite-sparse has been produced by academics and *is* maintained.

Comment: I personally can vouch for this code. I use it in my app and everything I have seen from Tim Davis is of the highest quality.

Comment: I would point out that Tim Davis' code is not free for commercial use. If you have a commercial product yourself then you will find his prices very reasonable. I personally use CSparse which is exceptionally good value.

Comment: @David:  I just looked.  CSparse is actually LGPL.

Comment: OK, so you have to ship a shared library then, or give up your code.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to actually get this up and running.  Works great.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I tangle LAPACK that I used old time ago and ARPACK that I used more time ago.

Here is link to arpack http://www.caam.rice.edu/~kristyn/parpack_home.html:
The package is designed to compute a few eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of a general n by n matrix A. It is most appropriate for large sparse or structured matrices.

And here link with comparison of libaries for Linear Algebra:

http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html

you can find there SparseLib++, mentioned here arpack and much more libaries in matrix form.

Comment: Without calling out the sparse codes in the enormous LAPACK, this is a non-answer. Can you edit to provide the missing details?

Comment: @David:  Good point.  I am actually using LAPACK now (though a wrapper, not directly) and I was under the impression that it didn't have any sparse support.  If I'm wrong, I'd love to be corrected because it would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: LAPACK itself doesn't do sparse matrices. The netlib repository has many good options.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated package called `CSPARSE`, and it's written in C. It seems that the implemention is based on [david2006direct].

- [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/csparse/csparse.html](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/c_src/csparse/csparse.html)
- Davis, T. A. (2006). Direct methods for sparse linear systems. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.